# Python tkinter checkbox. Обновление списка через onvalue, offvalue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

Не могу понять как можно к checkbox можно привязать команду. Мне нужно чтобы когда checkbox был активен, то он добавлял бы в список свою переменную, а когда он выключен, то соответственно удалял эту переменную из списка, но не у меня так и не получилось изменить список. Ниже код программы, она не закончена, т.к столкнулся с проблемой

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
# Команды

def show_graphic():
    if k:
        x = list(range(0,len(test)))
        plt.plot(x, test)
        plt.show()
        print(test)

def addbutton():
    a = box_1.get()
    if a:
        try:
            a = int(a)
            k.append(a)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Внимание!", "Вы ввели буквы")

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Внимание!","Пустое поле")
    # После проверки идет создание checkbutton (Максимум будет 10 checkbutton)
    for i in range(len(k)):
        print(k[i])
        for j in range(i+1):
            if j == 0:
                check1 = k[j]
                print("check1", check1)
                Checkbutton(win, text=check1, variable=check1,
                            onvalue=lambda check2, test: test.append(check2),
                            offvalue=lambda check2, test: test.remove(check2)
                            ).place(x=200 + j * 60, y=50)
            elif j == 1:
                check2 = k[j]
                print("check2", check2)
                Checkbutton(win, text=check2, variable=check2,
                            onvalue=lambda check2, test: test.append(check2),
                            offvalue=lambda check2, test: test.remove(check2)
                            ).place(x=200 + j * 60, y=50)
            elif j == 2:
                check3 = k[j]
                print("check3", check3)
                Checkbutton(win, text=check3, variable=check3,
                            onvalue=lambda check3, test: test.append(check3),
                            offvalue=lambda check3, test: test.remove(check3)
                            ).place(x=200 + j * 60, y=50)




# Основное окно
win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x400+500+50")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.title("Test")
# k - список для сбора данных из tk.Entry и последующего добавления его в checkbutton
# test - список который по идее должен изменяться в зависимости от положения checkbutt(On или Off)
k = []
test = []
# Заранее создал переменные для того чтобы добавлять их в список test
check1 = check2 = check3 = check4 = check5 = check6 = check7 = check8 = check9 = check10 = tk.IntVar()
tk.Label(win, text="Введите данные").place(x=10, y=10)
tk.Label(win, text="Введите процент").place(x=10, y=60)
# Поля для ввода данных
box_1 = tk.Entry(win, width=10)
box_1.place(x=10, y=30)
box_2 = tk.Entry(win, width=10)
box_2.place(x=10, y=80)
tk.Button(win, text="Добавить", command=addbutton).place(x=80, y=30)
tk.Button(win, text="Проверить график(Тест)", command=show_graphic).place(x=80, y=80)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чего-то у вас в коде с этими `Checkbutton` полная неразбериха.

- Во-первых, `onvalue` и `offvalue` - это значения, которые идут в `variable` когда ставят или снимают галочку.
- Во-вторых, процедура, которая вызывается при смене состояния `Checkbutton`, должна передаваться через параметр `command`.
- В-третьих, вроде бы у вас есть проверки на некорректный ввод, но после сообщений об ошибке ввода функция продолжает своё выполнение как ни в чём не бывало.
- В-четвёртых, у вас образуется лютое наслоение из `Checkbutton`, т.к. их новый набор каждый раз создаётся при вызове `addbutton()`. А предыдущие наборы никуда не деваются. Честно говоря, я не понял предназначения этих вложенных циклов для создания checkbutton'ов.

И ещё, ваш список `test` зависит от того в какой последовательность отмечались чекбоксы. Но не знаю, может так было задумано.

Ну, и, в общем, поправленный код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
# Команды

def show_graphic():
    if k:
        x = range(len(test))
        plt.plot(x, test)
        plt.show()
        print(test)

def checkbutton_changed(index):
    if check_vars[index].get():
        test.append(k[index])
    else:
        test.remove(k[index])

def addbutton():
    a = box_1.get()
    if a:
        try:
            a = int(a)
            if a in k:
                messagebox.showwarning("Внимание!", f"{a} уже было")
                return
            if len(k) < 10:
                k.append(a)
                box_1.delete(0, END)
            else:
                messagebox.showwarning("Внимание!", "Лимит достигнут")
                return
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Внимание!", "Вы ввели буквы")
            return

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Внимание!", "Пустое поле")
        return

    # После проверки идет создание checkbutton (Максимум будет 10 checkbutton)
    index = len(k) - 1
    Checkbutton(win, text=k[index], variable=check_vars[index],
                onvalue=1, offvalue=0, 
                command=lambda index=index: checkbutton_changed(index)
                ).place(x=200 + index * 60, y=50)


# Основное окно
win = Tk()
win.geometry("800x400+500+50")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.title("Test")

# k - список для сбора данных из tk.Entry и последующего добавления его в checkbutton
k = []
# test - список который по идее должен изменяться в зависимости от положения checkbutt(On или Off)
test = []
# Переменные хранящие состояние checkbutton'ов
check_vars = [tk.IntVar() for _ in range(10)]

tk.Label(win, text="Введите данные").place(x=10, y=10)
tk.Label(win, text="Введите процент").place(x=10, y=60)
# Поля для ввода данных
box_1 = tk.Entry(win, width=10)
box_1.place(x=10, y=30)
box_2 = tk.Entry(win, width=10)
box_2.place(x=10, y=80)
tk.Button(win, text="Добавить", command=addbutton).place(x=80, y=30)
tk.Button(win, text="Проверить график(Тест)", command=show_graphic).place(x=80, y=80)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за исправленный код, он мне помог мне улучшить свои навыки. Вложенный цикл по моей задумке должен был создавать checkbutton'ы на графическом интерфейсе, я пытался сделать так же как и вы, но не смог и по этому пришел к вложенному циклу. Сейчас я исправил немного ваш метод добавления. Мне нужно было чтобы при определенном количестве checkbutton (5 ед) они смещались на второй ряд. Сделал я это так
index = len(k) - 1
    if index < 5:
       Checkbutton(win, ... (Ваш код) ... return
    elif 10 > index >= 5
       Checkbutton(win .... (Ваш код) ... return
Надеюсь это правильно

Comment: @fallenkallen Эх... Любите вы ветвления. :) Можно же просто координаты правильно вычислить. Вместо `...).place(x=200 + index * 60, y=50)` можно написать `...).place(x=200 + index%5 * 60, y=30 + index//5*20)` - будет в 2 ряда по 5 штук со смещением 20 по Y. И никаких `if` не нужно.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, сказать как удалить эти чекбоксы? Они в переменную никак не записываются и как к ним обратиться я не знаю. В принципе это и не нужно, но для общего развития знать хотелось бы. Знаю только один метод это перезапустить программу